# INTNX in PROC SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm relatively new to SAS, so I'm sorry if I'm being kind of naive or silly with this question.

I'm trying to link the ending date to the initial date on my "where" clause through INTNX function, but the program returns results with a different date. I really do not know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using EG 8.2.

%LET ini_date = '10DEC2022'd;
%LET end_date = intnx('week',&inidate, 1);

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE FAT_CRED AS
SELECT *
FROM table A
WHERE A.DAT_MOV >= &ini_date.
AND A.DAT_MOV < &end_date.
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
;QUIT;

Strangely, the system returns end_date as Feb 3, 2020 (03FEB2020:00:00:00.000000), so I don't get any data from my query. I was expecting to gather the info between 10DEC and 16DEC, but I couldn't grasp if the problem lies in the compatibility between PROC SQL and the INTNX function (and its syntax), the date format in my table A, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try assigning a date literal to the macro variable instead of the function call.  See end of my updated answer.

Comment: @Tom, thank you so much for your help! It finally worked.

Also, thanks for your patience, it was my first post here, and I can't even cast a vote for your answer. If I could do something to highlight your answer and give it the proper credit, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of your confusion is that your variable appears to contain datetime values (you show a value of '03FEB2020:00:00:00.000000') and not actual date values.  SAS stores date values as days and datetime values as seconds.  So any reasonable date value is going to be some time in the early morning of January 1, 1960 if treated as a datetime value.

Either convert the datetime value to a date value before making the comparison

```
WHERE datepart(A.DAT_MOV) >= &ini_date.
  AND datepart(A.DAT_MOV) < &end_date.
```

Or generate datetime values into your macro variables.

```
%LET ini_date = '10DEC2022:00:00:00'dt; 
%LET end_date = "%sysfunc(intnx(dtweek,&ini_date, 1),datetime19.)"dt;
```

If using `"17DEC2022"d` works but using `22996` or `intnx('day','10DEC2022'd,7)` fails then you should use macro code to generate a date literal instead of just a date value.
You can use the `%SYSFUNC()` macro function call to invoke the `INTNX()` SAS function in your macro code.

```
%LET end_date = "%sysfunc(intnx(day,&ini_date, 7),date9.)"d;
```

Comment: Hi, Tom! Thanks for helping me.

I've found that I used the wrong arguments in INTNX. Actually, I need seven days after the ini_date. Therefore, the correct code would be 

%LET end_date = INTNX('DAY',&ini_date,7);

And I know that worked fine because after running the code below, I could get Dec 17, as I expected:

data temp;
Coluna_data = &end_date.;
FORMAT Coluna_data date9.;
run;

However, in the PROC SQL part I keep getting a blank table as a result of my query. It's probably a format issue with end_date (converting INTNX to date), but I couldn't find a way until now.

Comment: INTNX() defaults to move to the start of the interval.  You can add the 'SAME" option if you want it to move to the same relative point in the interval.  If you are moving by the unit that the values are stored in you can just use arithmetic.  To add 7 days to a date just add 7.  To add 60 seconds to a time or datetime value just add 60.

Comment: I'm sorry, Tom, maybe my explanation was not clear enough. The INTNX part is now working properly, the point is that when I run the PROC SQL bit, SAS returns a blank table, as if there was no result between the days I'm querying. Since I'm pretty sure ini_date is being properly read, there's something with end_date. I've been reading about PUT, INPUT, PUTN, INPUTN, but couldn't find a solution. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: Your original %LET statement was putting the CODE to call the INTNX() function into the macro.  Not the actual date value.  If you use the %SYSFUNC() macro function to call the INTNX() function, like in my example, then the value produced is something a human can see is a date.  Also run the query using the actual date values (not the macro variables) to see if there is in fact any data in the range you are looking for.  But first make to sure you use values that match the type of values in the variable, date literals for date values and datetime literals for datetime values.

Comment: I tested with the actual date values and there's data in the range. SAS is returning end_date = INTNX('DAY',&ini_date,7) = 22664, which is, in fact, the integer equivalent to Dec 17, the date that I need the program to consider. However, I'm unable to find a solution to convert this integer to date, and I don't even know where to write that. In my code, I declare the macro variables and start the PROC SQL code.

Comment: The integer, 22664, is the date 19JAN2022.  There is no difference in SAS code between the test `date<22664` and the test `date<"19JAN2022"d` both are comparing a number of days value to a number of days value.

Comment: I just tested 22996 (not 22664) on the where and didn't work. And it worked with '19DEC2022'd.

Comment: Show the log in your original question. Is your source data an actual SAS dataset? Or is the "dataset" you are querying actually coming from some external database such as Oracle?  Otherwise there is no reason why SAS would treat the two different ways to represent the number 22,996 differently.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've found that I was using the wrong arguments in INTNX function. I needed seven days after my ini_date, so the correct code is %LET END_DATE = INTNX('DAY',&INI_DATE,7);

After that, I run the PROC SQL part, but the program doesn't recognize end_date as I wish, because it reads it as integer (22996). How can I convert this to date in order to use it in the WHERE clause? please note: (1) the query runs fine when a use '17DEC2022'd in the ending date (2) I start PROC SQL right after I declare ini_date and end_date with %LET.

Thanks!

Comment: So you are setting the macro variable to the string you listed.  So if you used in in code then the SAS code it generates is what is run.  `A.DAT_MOV < INTNX('DAY','10DEC2022'd,7)` .  If you run with that does it work?

Comment: That didn't work too. Maybe because INTNX('DAY','10DEC2022'd,7) returns 22996, and I tested A>DAT_MOV < 22996 and got nothing as well.

You asked if there's some external database, and I'm sorry to say that I don't know for sure, but it's probably not a SAS dataset, since at the beginning of my code there's a libname with a password, a host, etc.

Comment: I made a mistake, I meant "DAT_MOV < 22996", sorry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 22996 is a SAS date value, that's the way SAS stores dates. You can format it into whatever date format you want, but, it wouldn't make a difference for the where clause. So, it should be used as it is in your where clause. If it's not working as expected, I would check the value of dat_mov.